# Change ondelete behavior on SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I have previously done:

```
ALTER TABLE `cms__model__file_taggable_tag` ADD CONSTRAINT 
cms__model__file_taggable_tag_id_cms__model__file_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES 
cms__model__file (id), ADD CONSTRAINT 
cms__model__file_taggable_tag_tag_id_taggable_tag_id FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) 
REFERENCES taggable_tag (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

but I meant to execute (forgot to add on update cascade constraint):

```
ALTER TABLE `cms__model__file_taggable_tag` ADD CONSTRAINT 
cms__model__file_taggable_tag_id_cms__model__file_id FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES 
cms__model__file (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT 
cms__model__file_taggable_tag_tag_id_taggable_tag_id FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) 
REFERENCES taggable_tag (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

How can I remove the previous constraints and apply the correct one?

---

Tried:

```
ALTER TABLE `cms__model__file_taggable_tag` DROP CONSTRAINT 
cms__model__file_taggable_tag_id_cms__model__file_id
```

got:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT 
cms__model__file_taggable_tag_id_cms__model__file_id' at line 1
```

Comment: Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName` to se if MySQL has actually created the constraint and if it has changed its name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName` to check if MySQL has actually created the constraint and if it has changed (truncated) its name.

Then use `DROP FOREIGN KEY`, not `DROP CONSTRAINT`:

```
ALTER TABLE cms__model__file_taggable_tag
  DROP FOREIGN KEY cms__model__file_taggable_tag_id_cms__model__file_id
```

Check the MySQL docs: **[ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)** and **[FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)**

Answer (score 2):

First,

`ALTER TABLE tablename DROP CONSTRAINT constraintname`

Then, put your corrected constraints back in.

*Edit: Didn't notice you were using MySQL. I believe MySQL's syntax is*

`ALTER TABLE tablename DROP INDEX indexname`

Comment: Try `DROP CONSTRAINT RESTRICT constraintname`

Comment: Terribly sorry, didn't notice you were using MySQL. I'm a Microsoft guy, but I believe MySQL uses the keyword `INDEX` instead of `CONSTRAINT`

Comment: I've already tried dropping the *index*, does not work either. Looks like I have to drop fk.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the word ADD with DROP in your ALTER clause